# Suppose x is a coordinate patch such that $g_{11} = 0$ and $g_{12}=0$. Prove that $u^1$ curves are geodesics.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose x is a coordinate patch such that $g_{11} = 0$ and $g_{12}=0$. Prove that $u^1$ curves are geodesics.

so the $u^1$ curve would be $x(u^1,b)$.

Then since $g_{11}=0$, $<x_1,x_1>=0$ so $x_1=0$ so the partial w.r.t. $u_1=0$.

Then since $g_{12}=0$, $<x_1,x_2>=0$ so $x_2$ could equal $0$ or not.

Then I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: This post needs more context.

Comment: Thats all the textbook gives

Comment: Well, then this question is unanswerable. I have no idea what $u^1$ is supposed to be. Also if I'm reading this right, the metric is not Riemannian?

Comment: Not even pseudo-Riemannian. Do you mean some derivatives of the $g_{ij}$ maybe? This feels like it was meant to be something related to Clairaut parametrizations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the actual problem says that $g_{11} \equiv 1$ (not $0$) and
$g_{12} \equiv 0$. Such a coordinate patch is called a geodesic coordinate patch. All notation used below are as in the book by Millman and Parker: Elements of Differential Geometry.

By $u^1$ curves, one means the following: fix $u^2$, and move in the $u^1$ direction. More precisely, we need to consider curves of the form $\gamma(t) = \text{x}(t,u^2)$ where $u^2$ is fixed. Notice that $\gamma' = \text{x}_1$ and $\gamma'' = \text{x}_{11}$. Note that the tangent vector of $\gamma$ is in the $\text{x}_1$ direction and $n$ is the normal direction, so the vector $S = n$ x $T$ is along the x$_2$ direction ($g_{12} = 0$ implies x$_1$,x$_2$,$n$ form an orthogonal basis).

By definition, the geodesic curvature is $<\gamma'',S>$. We want to show this is zero, so it is sufficient to show $< \text{x}_{11},\text{x}_2> = 0$. For this just play around with the equations. Take the $u^2$ derivative of the equation $< \text{x}_{1},\text{x}_1> \equiv 1$ and the $u^1$ derivative of the equation $< \text{x}_{1},\text{x}_2> \equiv 0$ to arrive at the result.